# Fabric (Crashlytics) does not deobfuscate exception stacktraces

Tags: android, maven, crashlytics

I've configured fabric with Maven and android-maven-plugin and i can see test exceptions in fabric dashboard. I've obfuscated the app but i can see obfuscated class/method names (i expect plugin to upload proguard mapping and show deobfuscated stacktraces instead).

I've checked to follow the [doc](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html#maven).
Also i can see 'mapping.txt' is saved in `./target/proguard/mapping.txt` instead of `./target/proguard_map.txt` which is expected by Fabric. I've checked `proguard.cfg` does not contain `-printmapping mapping.txt`.

I've tried to fix it by adding `mapping_location` to fabric plugin (though it's not clear in the doc to what plugin it should be added) like this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.crashlytics</groupId>
                <artifactId>crashlytics-maven</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>GenerateResources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>GenerateResources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>CleanupResources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>CleanupResources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mapping_location>${project.build.directory}/proguard/mapping.txt</mapping_location>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Also i can't see fabric plugin tries to find and upload that file to the server while building.

Note: i did not use fabric IDE plugin and i've added the app manually (it works for exceptions logging except deobfuscating for now). Any ideas?

PS. I'm usung android-maven-plugin 4.4.1 instead of 4.1.1 which is expected by Fabric (does it make sense?)

Comment: Hello! Did you find a way to resolve your issue ? I have the same issue with android-maven-plugin 4.4.3, but I suspect that mapping_location configuration is not working correctly..